# Lumen, laravel and pgsql SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

Tags: laravel, api, lumen

I was created rest API with Lumen and pgsql in my localhost then its running perfect when I test to call my API with postman, then I run php artisan migrate on server production in cloud and run success. But when I call my API in cloud it show error like this

```
{
    "code": "500",
    "message": "SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: select `id`, `payment` from `myDb` where `client_id` = xxxxx and `client_secret` = xxxxxxx limit 1)",
    "data": null
}
```

Please someone can help me.
Thanks advance

Comment: any progress ??

Comment: can i look at the .env file ?